# UIButton setFrame unrecognized selector alignmentRectInsets

Tags: ios

This is my first time adding UI elements programmatically. The app is crashing with an error:

```
2014-01-14 18:39:50.080 Convention[27580:70b] -[__NSCFConstantString alignmentRectInsets]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c028
2014-01-14 18:40:00.792 Convention[27580:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString alignmentRectInsets]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c028'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x023f55e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01fe48b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02492903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x023e590b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0242246e __forwarding_prep_1___ + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x00fe2305 -[UIButton alignmentRectInsets] + 217
    6   UIKit                               0x013b605b -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) alignmentRectForFrame:] + 52
    7   UIKit                               0x00fdf7f0 -[UIButton contentRectForBounds:] + 104
    8   UIKit                               0x00fe2448 -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 100
    9   UIKit                               0x00dbd267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01ff681f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0029f2ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    12  QuartzCore                          0x002930d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    13  QuartzCore                          0x002a1715 -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 43
    14  UIKit                               0x00dafc76 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 595
    15  UIKit                               0x00fdb18c -[UIButton setFrame:] + 182
    16  Convention                          0x0006c020 -[CIFinalCustomerInfoViewController viewDidLoad] + 1760
    17  UIKit                               0x00e66318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
```

The error is happening during execution of `cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(62.0, currentY+8.0, 162.0, 56.0);`. Following is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BOOL contactb4ShippingConfig = ([ShowConfigurations instance].contactBeforeShipping);
    originalBounds = self.view.bounds;
    CGFloat currentY = 404.0;
    if (contactb4ShippingConfig) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62.0, currentY, 300.0, 35.0)];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura Medium Italic" size:27.0f];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.text = @"Contact Before Shipping";
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [self.view addSubview:contactBeforeShippingCB];
        currentY = currentY + 35.0;
    }
    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:@"cart-cancelout.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:@"cart-cancelin.png" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(62.0, currentY+8.0, 162.0, 56.0);
    UIButton *submitButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [submitButton setBackgroundImage:@"submitorderout.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [submitButton setBackgroundImage:@"submitorderin.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    submitButton.frame = CGRectMake(62.0, cancelButton.frame.origin.y, 260.0, 56.0);
    currentY = cancelButton.frame.origin.y;
    [self.view addSubview:cancelButton];
    [self.view sizeToFit];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Extremely well asked question. You provided the crash message, the crash log, the code, and you stated the line on which the crash occurred, suggesting that you already walked through in the debugger. Bravo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is these lines:

```
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:@"cart-cancelout.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:@"cart-cancelin.png" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment them out and all will be well. This suggests that we are failing to find the images in question.

**EDIT later:** Well, I'm rather careless, I'm afraid; I figured out the problematic lines purely by trial and error, but I completely failed to notice correctly *what* was wrong with them! As you rightly say, it's that these are strings, not images. And indeed we should have known this from the original error message: "`-[__NSCFConstantString alignmentRectInsets]`" means exactly that a string has been supplied where some other class was expected, so all we had to do was look for some rogue strings in your code.

(Your code has some other problems but not the kind of problems that would cause this crash.)

Comment: The issue was my using strings instead of UIImage instances in those calls. Using `[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cart-cancelout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]` fixed the issue. Thanks for your help! And do let me know what other issues you see in this code, like I said this is my first time adding ui programmatically and I want take to care of all gotchas.

Comment: For example, don't force `view` resizing and layout in `viewDidLoad`; it's pointless, as (1) it is not yet layout time (the view is not yet in the window) and (2) it will be done automatically in just a moment anyway. - Also, you created `submitButton` but never added it to the interface. - And `originalBounds` is not declared; if it is an instance variable, you should write in a way that clarifies that fact, lest you confuse yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is process of elimination.

Remove all the code and try adding only this much code.

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:@"cart-cancelout.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:@"cart-cancelin.png" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(62.0, 100+8.0, 162.0, 56.0);
[self.view addSubview:cancelButton];
```

If this compiles and works then add a bit more to it till you find where its tripping up.

Comment: Exactly so. Actually the heuristic is the other way round: comment out or simplify bits of code until the code suddenly works. That is how I got my answer; I commented out sets of lines until the code worked. Thus, what was commented out was clearly the problem. The difficulty here is that the _mistake_ was in the `setBackgroundImage:` lines, but the _crash_ doesn't happen until later.